# Strategies on storing raw scraped HTML in conjunction with extracted fields using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, storage, database-performance

**Problem:**

I scrape ~2.5-3gb worth of HTML data on a daily basis, and following the day's scrapes, I extract certain fields from each page and store them in a MongoDB collection, where the extracted fields are in the same document as the HTML that they were extracted from. I'm starting to consider that maybe I should store these in separate collections though. Here's my reasoning:

HTML field:

- Never altered
- Never used in any computationally expensive algorithms
- Never queried from our database's dashboard

All other fields:

- Some fields are changed consistently in computationally expensive programs
- Used heavily in computationally expensive programs
- Queried relatively frequently via the database's dashboard

Note: A couple minor details on "computationally expensive" - the main program that comes to mind is a matching algorithm, run daily, which runs 14-16 parallel processes that all read/write the collection heavily. One of the fields that gets updated consistently during this algorithm is an indexed field. I try to use projections and batch size increases where they seem useful, but I do not project on every query.

We're coming up on ~30 million documents in the collection, thus indexes are starting to get very large.

**Questions:**

- Will removing the raw HTML from the collection increase performance on reads and/or writes?
- Since I rarely query the HTML, should I even bother with a MongoDB collection and instead consider storing/compressing it in the regular file system?

I'm happy to provide additional details on request...just figured I would keep it relatively general to start with.

Thanks a ton!